# Is WPF stronger than Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is WPF include all the feature of Windows Form + Additional Feature? Because I found some of features of WinForms are not available in WPF.

update me! The importance of Windows Form than WPF.

Comment: I think [this post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) answers your question exactly.

Answer (score 3):

WPF is a completely different approach to user interfaces than Windows Forms.

It has a much more flexible design, which allows you to do a lot more things, often with cleaner code.  This is especially true when you fully take advantage of the data binding support in WPF.

However, Windows Forms is *very* mature - as such, there is a huge, mature ecosystem built around it.  This does include some tooling and features that don't exist in WPF.

That being said, most new development within the .NET Framework related to user interfaces is XAML based.  I would strongly suggest using WPF or Silverlight over Windows Forms for any new development.  I wrote a detailed series on [migrating to WPF from Windows Forms](http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/) which discusses many of the benefits and advantages of WPF.